# How to change the datatype of the output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want the output of this code in int64 format but the output of this code is in float. how can change it? pls suggest

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/HqjNNadqEnwSq1qnoV_JqyRJkc7o6O')
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 5]
print(round(100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index))),2)
```

Comment: `df = df.astype(np.int64)`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/HqjNNadqEnwSq1qnoV_JqyRJkc7o6O')
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 5]

x = round(100*(df.isnull().sum()/len(df.index)))
y = x.astype(np.int64)

print(y)
```

The key bit being x.astype(np.int64) to convert the format.